# Variable scope issue with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I have a really weird issue with my javascript page :

```
    $scope.ptfs = new Array();

    $http.get('trades.json').success(function(data) {
            data.portfolios.forEach(function(p){
                $scope.ptfs.push(new Portfolio(p.id , p.name));

                $scope.message3 = $scope.ptfs[0];

            })
    })

    $scope.message2 = $scope.ptfs;
    $scope.message4 = $scope.ptfs[0];
```

And the HTML :

```
2 : {{message2}}<br>
3 : {{message3}}<br>
4 : {{message4}}<br>
```

The result i got is :
2 : [{"id":0,"name":"CAN REAL","trades":[]},{"id":1,"name":"INVESTOPEDIA","trades":[]}]
3 : {"id":0,"name":"CAN REAL","trades":[]}
4 :

Any idea why : 
- $scope.message3 = $scope.ptfs[0]; AND
- $scope.message4 = $scope.ptfs[0];

doesn't return the same result ?

Thanks,
Nicolas

Comment: What if you try setting the scope variables inside the success function? I bet this is an async issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you encounter is due to the asynchronous nature of your code. `$scope.message4 = $scope.ptfs[0];` is executed before items get pushed to `$scope.ptfs`. At the time of assigning `message4`, your array is empty.

`$http.get('trades.json')` returns a promise. Once that promise is resolved, ie. once the server responds to your request, the callback of the `then` function is executed `$scope.ptfs` is populated.

Comment: thanks.Any way to go around that ?
Except to put all the code inside the .success ?

Comment: It all depends on what you want to achieve. You can force to delay the instantiation of your controller until the data requested to the server is available. This can be achieve using `resolve` in ngRoute of uiRouter.